# I have registered but can't sign in

Tags: discussion, login

I have registered and logged in previously (a couple of days ago). My password no longer works, and the reset code that gets sent to me (I've tried three or four times) does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link to your other account?

Comment: What kind of account did you link to your AskUbuntu account? Google, Yahoo, Launchpad, etc. Or did you create a StackExchange account?